# How do you move an armour stand two blocks ahead of its position in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make an armour stand teleport 2 blocks in front of its natural position?

Answer (score 2):

`execute as @e[type=armor_stand,sort=nearest,limit=1] at @s run tp @s ^ ^ ^2`